# How do you use cloningInfo to create azure slot?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to add a slot to my template, and would like to just have it clone the production slot's configuration (just like the portal offers).  It seems that cloningInfo is the way to do this, but the sourceWebAppId does not seem to be enough to get this done.  When I specify just that propery, I get a HTTP error which is not helpful.  I can't find any example templates that use cloningInfo to replicate a slot.

Here is what I have as a resource to my website resource:

```
                {
                "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
                "name": "staging",
                "type": "slots",
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "dependsOn": [
                    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', variables('webSiteName'))]"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "cloningInfo":{
                        "sourceWebAppId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', variables('webSiteName')), '2016-08-01')]"
                    }
                },
                "tags": {}
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a WebApp hosted on **Premium** App Service Plans.

We could use the following ARM template to clone the WebApp. [sourceWebAppId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites#CloningInfo) is the resoure id of the WebApp. And we also need the serverfarm id.

**Note:**

- the slot name is **WebsiteName/xxxx**
- How to scale up your pricing tier, please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-scale#scale-up-your-pricing-tier).

**ARM template:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "webSiteName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The site name. To use the default value, do not specify a new value."
      }
    },
    "ServicePlanName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The host name. To use the default value, do not specify a new value."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },

  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('webSiteName'), '/staging')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
      "apiVersion": "2016-08-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "tags": {},
      "properties": {
        "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('ServicePlanName'))]",
        "cloningInfo": {
          "sourceWebAppId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites/', parameters('webSiteName'))]"

        }
      },
      "resources": [
      ]
    }
  ],

  "outputs": {}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this not work with Standard?  You mention Premium like that's required, and I know Shared and Basic does not support slots, but Standard does.  Or am I missing something else that would prevent this working with Standard?

Comment: So this is only available to Isolated, Premium and PremiumV2.  I get an error, even though I can effectively do this in the Azure Portal. Will revert to manual cloning for my app.  Not Ideal!